# how would I run this?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, navicat

how do I run the following code in mysql query browser or navicat? I tried to run it as a query and that gave me errors. I want to know do I just put this in query or what?

```
use nydb;
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS testProc;
CREATE PROCEDURE testProc()
BEGIN

  # do something

DELIMITER ;
call testProc();
DROP PROCEDURE testProc;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested on 5.1.58

```
use nydb;

delimiter $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS testProc$$
CREATE PROCEDURE testProc()
BEGIN

  select 1 from dual;

END $$

DELIMITER ;

call testProc();

DROP PROCEDURE testProc;
```